# DNS is sometimes returning the wrong IP address for a website

Tags: raspbian, dns

I have a Pi4 running Raspbian desktop using NetworkManager for IP management. I have two wifi networks, one for general internet access and the other to access a device with fixed IP of 5.8.8.8.

I am having issues with the wrong IP address being used to access some websites, specifically 5.8.8.8.

For example,the DNS entry for raspbian.raspberrypi.org is:

```
pi@docker:~ $ dig raspbian.raspberrypi.org

; <<>> DiG 9.16.27-Raspbian <<>> raspbian.raspberrypi.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49633
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;raspbian.raspberrypi.org.      IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
raspbian.raspberrypi.org. 258   IN      CNAME   mirrordirector.raspbian.org.
mirrordirector.raspbian.org. 558 IN     A       93.93.128.193

;; Query time: 9 msec
;; SERVER: 100.100.100.100#53(100.100.100.100)
;; WHEN: Sat Apr 02 17:07:24 BST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 99
```

But sometimes I get:

```
pi@docker:~ $ dig raspbian.raspberrypi.org

; <<>> DiG 9.16.27-Raspbian <<>> raspbian.raspberrypi.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42557
;; flags: qr aa ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;raspbian.raspberrypi.org.      IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
raspbian.raspberrypi.org. 0     IN      A       5.8.8.8

;; Query time: 19 msec
;; SERVER: 100.100.100.100#53(100.100.100.100)
;; WHEN: Sat Apr 02 17:14:10 BST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 58
```

It appears the same server was used in both queries so how can this server (obviously not on my network and hence ignorant of 5.8.8.8) be returning this incorrect answer?

EDIT:
For what its worth, here is the routing info:

```
pi@docker:~ $ ip route
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 200 
default via 5.8.8.8 dev wlan1 proto dhcp metric 600 
5.8.8.0/24 dev wlan1 proto kernel scope link src 5.8.8.9 metric 600 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-48a4aec1d585 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-594694ddefe4 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 
172.30.32.0/23 dev hassio proto kernel scope link src 172.30.32.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.92 metric 200
```

Comment: May or may not be related to your problem, but assigning some device *with a real, already extent IP address* (5.8.8.8) that is [obviously not that device](https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/5.8.8.8) is an incredibly bad idea that is bound to cause some grief at some point.  It certainly means that "this server obviously not on my network" is **not** ignorant of 5.8.8.8, but which one (the real one, or yours) applies when may be arbitrary.

Comment: That aside, you have referred to "two wifi networks" but provided no routing information, which makes diagnosing the problem more difficult, particularly if your routing is wrong...which there is a big clue here that it easily could be.

Comment: This [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=DNS+with+IP+address+%225.8.8.8%22&client=safari&channel=mac_bm&source=hp&ei=puRJYvrYF-OOwbkPhouT0A0&iflsig=AHkkrS4AAAAAYknytqVoUvN9VqDJsheKNZ4Amsl8eMfc&ved=0ahUKEwj6w6-pwPj2AhVjRzABHYbFBNoQ4dUDCAw&uact=5&oq=DNS+with+IP+address+%225.8.8.8%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABUABYAGDQD2gAcAB4AIABaYgBaZIBAzAuMZgBAKABAqABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) may shed some light on your issues... wondering how 5.8.8.8 wound up as a sole destination for one of your WiFi networks? Just curious - you needn't answer - just trying to understand your objectives.

Comment: @goldilocks, I have added details of the routing to the OP. I didn't originally include it as I thought it was a DNA issue rather than a routing one.

Comment: @Seamus, I have an inverter for the solar panels. This kit has a fixed IP address (5.8.8.8) and has its own AP. It can connect to my "main" wifi but the API I want to access is only exposed to its own network. Weird, but I can't change it.

Comment: Whoever made that kit is a bit of twit, IMO -- there are [plenty of private IP address ranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses) that could have been used.  Possibly it is because the device has no writable storage and they didn't want a conflict with those ranges, and instead chose the public IP of a Russian RDNS server.  What could go wrong!

Comment: I agree w/ @goldilocks assessment: you're either the victim of stupidity or evil. I'm fairly certain no one here can help you - and your question seems very much off-topic given the circumstances. For that reason only, I'm going to vote to close the question. Just outta' curiosity, where did you buy this thing? ...can you return it??  Best of luck in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo ip route del default via 5.8.8.8 dev wlan1
```

The default route is the one used when nothing else applies, which is usually the case for general web stuff; the "via" address is a gateway router.

If you end up with multiple default (or other overlapping) routes, which one gets used is determined by the "metric", lower values are preferred.  However, those values are malleable: There can be a purpose to such overlap/duplication, eg., if one or all of the gateways is prone to congestion, some bit of software may dynamically change the metrics based on round-trip times etc.

In your case there is no such good purpose, because 5.8.8.8 is not a gateway.  However -- and this is by no means definite, it's conjecture -- the software tweaking the metrics don't know that.  If the device responds to DNS queries with its own address, and/or responds to any address for some things (since it works as an AP to itself and nothing else), this could lead to the problem you observe.

Again, this is just a guess, but deleting that route is easy and cannot do any harm.  There is already a separate route for 5.8.8.0/24 which handles legitimate traffic to the device.

#### Another Possibility...

Is that network software has solicited the device "network" for DNS servers, and it provided one, itself, which it may function as one that just returns its own address as described above.  Because of that, it gets listed in the system's list of DNS servers, `/etc/resolv.conf`.

If it is there, there is even less point than the spurious default route, and what's worse is it is almost certain to cause a problem, especially if this dead-end nameserver claims to know where everything is and that place is 5.8.8.8 (which is the behaviour you are observing).

Chances are there is a comment in resolv.conf about what put the listing in it, and that is either `systemd-resolvd` or `NetworkManager`.  I don't use either of those, so if this is the case you will have to find out how to blacklist a nameserver using them.

In any case, removing it won't matter, and hopefully NM or whatever doesn't immediately put it back.  Most likely they just do this when a DHCP lease has been established.  So you should be able to edit that out and see if it solves the problem.  Then you can make it permanent using whatever methodology is appropriate to the networking tools you are using.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I have tried it (so the "default via 5.8.8.8 dev wlan1 proto dhcp metric 600" is now missing) but the problem presists.

Comment: Try looking in `/etc/resolv.conf` and see if 5.8.8.anything is in there -- it shouldn't be, this is the list of DNS servers in use.

Comment: Yes, it is. The file contains a line "nameserver 5.8.8.8". How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I've rebooted and now resolv.conf is completely different and has been provided by tailscale. This one contains 100.100.100.100 (which explains where that address comes from). The one with 5.8.8.8 in it was generated by NM. Maybe there's a race condition going on here or I did something to get back to the NM version. Either way, it still looks like a routing issue to me, where 100.100.100.100 is being routed to 5.8.8.8.

Comment: Almost certainly having it listed as a nameserver is the problem and removing it should solve that.  I've edited some stuff in about that above.  The nameservers are solicited as part of the DHCP lease(s).

Comment: I'll give it a go to see whether it helps, but I'm not convinced yet. The output from dig in my OP shows the DNS server 100.100.100.100 is sometime being routed to 5.8.8.8. That is not the result of a DNS look-up but a routing decision. If that is the case, the presence of 5.8.8.8 as a DNS server is a red herring (but still wrong).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in the end to (hopefully) fix the problem. Certainly I haven't seen the symptons for a couple of days although I'm not convinced this is a 100% fix. Anyway, FWIW this is what I did.

The problem was that NetworkManager was picking up 5.8.8.8 as a DNS, which it wasn't. It was also complicated by the fact that I had tailscale installed which was also overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf` with its own DNS (as I had MagicDNS enabled). This was why 100.100.100.100 was being used as a DNS and the incorrect route of "default via 5.8.8.8" meant that the DNS request aimed at 100.100.100.100 was ending up at 5.8.8.8, hence the dig response seeming to indicate that 100.100.100.100 was providing duff DNS answers.

So the first thing was to stop tailscale from imposing its own DNS, which was done on the tailscale admin screen. This left NW setting the DNS list, incorrectly including 5.8.8.8. To stop this, I editted `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to change "dns=default" to "dns=none". This stops NW from extracting the list of DNSs from the DHCP responses. Not ideal since now I had to set them manually but hey. Before I made this change, I noted the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`.

The next step was to edit `/etc/resolv.cong` to remove the "nameserver 5.8.8.8" line. A reboot later and things are working ok.

I am still left with the "default via 5.8.8.8" line in the routing table. I tried adding a line to `/etc/rc.local` to delete this, which sort-of works but it keeps re-appearing. Not sure why but my guess is that NW is doing a check periodically and re-adding it.